# Automate a crawler/program to download csv based on gif calendar selection

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, testing, phantomjs

So I have something like this to fetch daily csv, there is a calendar icon and whenever I click it resets to basic date (since it is a gif base with js written over it). The input is calendar based. post that need to just fetch the respective csv for the date.
Need to automate this.

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$dt" type="text" maxlength="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder3_dt" readonly="true" /><span style="display:inline-block;width:5px;"></span><img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder3_dt" onmouseover="fnInitCalendar(this, &#39;ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder3_dt&#39;,&#39;instance=single,close=true&#39;)" src="../Images/calendar.gif" style="border-width:0px;" /><script language='javascript' src='../JS/calendar.js'></script><LINK href='../CSS/calendar.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

is the input line on source

Might sound easy for someone who is good at web testing, my guess is phantom.js or selenium can be pretty useful here but I don't know how to use it.

(Unable to post an image because less than 10 reputation ..)

Comment: try to put code what you have tried yet

Comment: You are saying that you don't know how to use it, but have you tried? This video will help you to start : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAQQBeZ1iV4&t=168s